# Getting "JSONObject["myKey"] is not a JSONArray."

Tags: java, json

I have a bit of code that has been working for years

```
JSONObject variableData = new JSONObject(request.getParameter("VARIABLE_DATA"));
JSONArray companies = variableData.getJSONArray("COMPANIES");
```

and today, I get the following error:

```
JSONObject["COMPANIES"] is not a JSONArray.
```

I have stopped the code prior to executing the getJSONArray() call and looked into variableData.  Here is what I find:

```
{"COMPANIES":[{"COMPANY":"2"}]}
```

To me, this looks like a valid JSONArray to be pulled from a valid JSONObject, so I'm flummoxed and looking for help.  Thanks.

Comment: there is a suprising number of JSON implementations, which one are you using? some of those convert arrays of length 1 into an object (which is quite annoying.

Comment: To follow up on @dube's comment, where do you load your JSON libraries and more importantly, could anyone have replaced them with updated versions? That might well be the problem.

Comment: JSON being used is org-json-2012-07-16.jar and is company-wide, so changing implementations would not be a first choice.  This is being pulled in by Gradle as part of the dependencies for the project.

Comment: try variableData.getJSONObject("COMPANIES") and use all the isXXX methods on it to check what type the object is. Maybe it's a JSONObject or something, as mentioned above.

Comment: similar error `JSONObject["COMPANIES"] is not a JSONObject`

Comment: Having spent a good deal of the day looking into this, it appears that there is an issue with an internal package which has classes which extend JSONObject and JSONArray.  I appreciate all of the helpful comments and suggestions.  I will delete this post if asked to do so, but I think there may be some helpful info for future readers so I won't do it out-of-hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your piece of code works fine when using `org.json-20120521.jar`. I think there is something wrong with the jar you are using. 
[image]

Comment: that works under the JSON implementation currently in use.  there seems to be something about the way the JSONObject is formed OR the way the JSONArray is formed within the JSONObject that is now causing something to look invalid.

Comment: did you reslove it? If not have a look at this issue and see if its the cause of your problem:https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20180

Comment: I have not resolved this issue, but it looks like it is an internal issue rather than a standard API use issue.  When I get to the bottom of the issue, I will update or delete this post.

Comment: this started working again - "suddenly" so I'm thinking there was a dependency issue that someone else found and resolved.

Comment: @user3487063, I replaced my library with org.json-20120521.jar but still has same issue. Anyone found alternative solution to this issue?

Answer (score -1):

But "COMPANIES":[{"COMPANY":"2"}] is not a valid json. Other question that I would ask is the exception reproducible? Did you get this data from exact same request that produced the exception? Is there a chance that your server got corrupted data? Try to write a unit test that covers this case and check were it takes you.

Comment: The JSON is valid. The rest of your answer should be a comment.

Comment: The JSON is valid, because CoMo G-Dawg updated if after my question.

Comment: I did go back in and edit the question for clarity and completeness.  It did not look like a JSONArray within a JSONObject, which it is.